# list in a 2D list a column python

Tags: python, pandas, list

```py
main_list=[
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['800800', '802100', '800905'],
    ['Kartoffel  -FESTKOCHEND-', 'Princes/Belana', '(1  x  25  kg./Sack)', 'Orangen,  Press-/Saftorangen', '(1  x  90er-St./Ktn.)', 'Möhren,  lose  (gross', '(1  x  10  Kg/Sack)'],
    ['30', '56', '35'],
    ['1', '1', '1'],
    ['30,00  KG', '56,00  Kin.', '35,00  KG'],
    ['10,00', '10,00', '6,80'],
    ['300,00”  1', '/', '560,00  1', '238.00‘  4']
]
```

I want to make each list in a 2-dimensional list a column and add as many headers as there are columns. but in my code every element comes as a line.

```
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=main_list)
cols = list(dataFrame.columns.values)
index = 1   
for column in cols:
    cols[index-1] = "unnamed"+str(index)                    
    index += 1 
newDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(main_list,columns=cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the transpose of the first data frame you are creating to get each list as a column instead of a row.

```
dataFrame.transpose()
```

Comment: With transpose, the index drops to 7 (because it takes the list with the highest element)

Comment: yes that is how it will be unless you edit that 3rd list properly so that all the lists will have 3 items only. Then you will get 3 rows.